# Creating a variable key from another variable name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have `t` which equals `mapType`

`var t = 'mapType'`

I am trying to get the following result

```
mapTypeControlOptions: {
};
```

But when I try `t[ControlOptions]: {}` it comes up with an error for using square brackets, is there a way to get this to work?

My end result is

```
map.setOptions({
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    }
});
```

But I want to dynamically build it so that `mapType` and `TOP_LEFT` change depending on the variables

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObject = {};
var t = 'mapType';

myObject[ t + 'ControlOptions' ] = {};
// after your edit: no you can call 
// map.setOptions( myObject );

console.log( myObject );
// Object {mapTypeControlOptions: Object} 

console.log( myObject[ 'mapTypeControlOptions' ] );
// Object {}

console.log( myObject[ t +'ControlOptions' ] );
// Object {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build key names like that, the object passed into map.setOptions() will need creating separately.

E.g. I've created it as an empty object "settings" below, modifying it based on your chosen 't' variable (mapType), and then passed it into the Google map via map.setOptions():

```
var t = 'mapType';
var settings = {};

// Add to settings object using key prefix 't'
settings[t + 'ControlOptions'] = {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
};

// Pass into map
map.setOptions(settings);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var mapType = {};
mapType.ControlOptions: {
};
```